# SASS variables inter-files scope

Tags: sass, compass-sass

In order to use

```
@include box-shadow(0 0 10px black);
```

you would have to include the "library":

```
@import "compass/css3";
```

later in the file, I am including other scss:

```
@import "sidebar/main";
```

and in that sidebar/_main.scss, when i call the same:

```
@include box-shadow(0 0 10px black);
```

compass breaks with an error:

```
< ... Undefined mixin 'box-shadow'.>
```

Does this mean that I'll have to abstract the libraries in my own library file, and then include that file in each and every other scss???

Answer (score 2):

Rename the sidebar/main.scss to sidebar/**_main**.scss - no other code changes needed.

This instructs sass compiler not to compile the sidebar/main.scss file into a separate css file, but include it in the main scss file.

The process works like this:

sass compiles the main scss file with all inclusions and generates the css (no errors here, since compass is included at top)
sass compiles all other scss files that don't begin with _, but since these don't have compass included, it throws the error.

Comment: I'm aware of the '_' functionality. I already have that file named _main.scss. The problem is that it is not aware of the variables defined in the previous file - the one that includes sidebar/_main.scss.

Comment: Then you can safely include compass requirements in the second file too. This will not bloat the code because it contains only @mixins (the css3 at least), they are not compiled.

Comment: It's what I did. But I don't fancy that approach. I don't like including that file in each and every other scss because I tend to go very granular about organizing the views into sub-directories.